# Getting 'undefined' returned when trying to sort array of objects with TimSort

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting, timsort

Here is a code snippet that is very close to what I'm trying to implement in my project: https://repl.it/@Twinbird24/TimSort-example

```
var timsort = require('timsort');

const arr = [
  {
    name: 'Amy',
    age: 23
  },
  {
    name: 'Bob',
    age: 34
  },
  {
    name: 'Cary',
    age: 18
  }
];

function sort(objectsArr, sortBy, sortOrder = 'ascending') {
  function stringCompare(a, b) {
    return a.sortBy - b.sortBy;
  }
  return timsort.sort(objectsArr, stringCompare);
}

const sortedArr = sort(arr, 'name');

console.log(sortedArr);
```

Here is the package I'm using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/timsort

I'm trying to sort my array of objects by each object's name property, which holds a string—although my function can also be passed another item to sort by (i.e. 'age').

The documentation for TimSort is not very clear and looking through the source code I'm still not quite able to figure out how to configure my code.

You'll notice in my code that I would also like to choose to sort by 'ascending' or 'descending' but I'm not sure how to add that into the TimSort method I'm using.

Comment: If you are having trouble with the library, then [ask the library author](https://github.com/mziccard/node-timsort/issues)

Comment: Based on the examples, i'd assume it is an in place sort and returns nothing. [The source](https://github.com/mziccard/node-timsort/blob/master/src/timsort.js#L910) seems to confirm that.

Comment: Why do you call `x - y` a StringCompare?  You can't compare Strings with subtraction!

Comment: also, does `a` and `b` have a `sortBy` property? pretty sure they don't, and you need to use bracket notation there.

Comment: Timsort.sort() does not return a sorted version of the array. Instead It modifies the array you've passed into it.

`const arr = [
  5,4,1
];
timsort.sort(arr);
console.log(arr); // 1,4,5`

Comment: @smac89 I could ask the library author, but: 1) what's wrong with asking here? The problem isn't inherently a library problem: [FAQ: what can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). 2) there are some issues open on the repo but from what I see it's not very active, while here I get feedback within minutes. Not sure why your comment got upvotes, it's a step up from "Google it" - it provides no value and you word it as though it's not something I considered but something I should have done instead of coming here (which brings me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string compare doesn't compare strings.  It will only work for types like numbers or those that have a `valueOf`, like Date.

Perhaps if you changed it to `a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0`, it would work a little better.  So how about this?:

```
function sort(objectsArr, sortBy, sortOrder = 'ascending') {
  function stringCompare(a, b) {
    const left = a[sortBy], right = b[sortBy];
    return left < right ? -1 : left > right ? 1 : 0;
  }
  return timsort.sort(objectsArr, stringCompare);
}
```

This still doesn't answer you ascending/descending question.  It should be straightforward from here, but please ask another question if you can't get it.

Comment: Adding this for posterity.  For ascending/descending just switch the return in the compare function.  "return a.age - b.age;" to "b.age - a.age;"